# Make [if-clause] a synonym of [if-statement]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

`if...else` === `if...else`, therefore [if-clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/if-clause) should be a synonym of [if-statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/if-statement).

Comment: I've suggested it here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/if-statement/synonyms